# Rails 5, Passing param to query - is it secure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Someone may asked it before, however I need to check it

AFAIK, this is secure (Rails 5.1)

`user = User.where(email: params[:user][:email]).first`

If not please let me know why?

Comment: Yes it is, what is dangerous is to use params without filtering it, and when you create/update records with it. This is not what you're doing. But then it depend of what you do with this `user`. You should detail the whole action.

Comment: if `params[:user]` is `nil` you will get an exception

Comment: yes, there is a checking for nil before this line.

Comment: or `params.fetch(:user, :email)`, that takes care if either is `nil`

Answer (score 1):

It is secure in the sense that it you don't need to escape or `permit` the parameter.

- Rails will automatically escape the param to protect you from SQL injection
- You do not need to worry about [strong parameters](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) or use `permit`, since you are not doing a mass assignment

So the code will do exactly what it says it does.

However, it may still be "insecure" in the sense that whoever calls this action can query *any* user in the database.

In general this is only safe if the caller is authenticated **and** is allowed to see **all** users in the database. Otherwise anybody can quickly check which users exist, and maybe worse.